# R Shiny: Run dynamic For loop from uploaded data

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I need some help in my Shiny App. I am creating a Shiny App, where the user can upload a pre-defined template with data, view it & be able to run linear models. My problem is, I am not able to run the "For" loops. I have a "For" loop within a "For" loop to run. Basically, what I am looking at is, run linear models for each of the iteration of the "For" loops.

First "For" loop to filter data for a year and then second "For" loop to run for each of the parameter within a year. If I hard code "For" loop values (Ex: Year == "2018" & Parameter == "LDPP"), App works fine but not when I try to run the loop with dynamic values `ynames[y]` or `tnames[t]` in the code.

#### Sample Data

```
Year <- rep(c("2018", "2019"), each = 48)
Zone <- rep(c("South", "West"), each = 24, times = 4)
Location <- rep(c("Bangalore", "Hyderabad", "Ahmedabad", "Gandhinagar"), each = 12, times = 2)
Product <- rep(c("E-Esta", "PAN-60065", "PAN-60098"), each = 4, times = 8)
Rep <- rep(c(1:2), times = 48)
Parameter <- rep(c("FFRM", "FSTR"), times = 48)
Value <- rnorm(96)

data <- data.frame(Year, Zone, Location, Product, Rep, Parameter, Value)
```

#### Code with For Loop - This is not running as expected

```
library(shiny) 
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT) 
library(readxl)
library(lme4) 
shinyApp(ui <- navbarPage("Pluto",
      tabPanel("Data Import & Preview",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(width = 2,
            fileInput("file1", "Upload the updated template (only 1 Sheet)", accept = ".xlsx")
            ),
          mainPanel(h2("Data Preview"), DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"), width = 4)
                        )) ,
        tabPanel("Data Analysis",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(width = 2, 
                 actionButton("analysis", "Fire")),
             
             fluidRow(width = 20,
               tabBox(id = "trans",
                 tabPanel("Names View", verbatimTextOutput("tnames", placeholder = T), 
                          verbatimTextOutput("ynames", placeholder = T)),
                 tabPanel("Variance Components", DT::dataTableOutput("varcomp")),
                 tabPanel("Pred Values", DT::dataTableOutput("pred"))
                 
                 )
              )
            )
          )
      ),
server <- function(input, output, session){
data <- reactive({
  req(input$file1)
  read_xlsx(input$file1$datapath)
  })

tnames <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
} else {
  tnames <- data() %>% unique(data()$Trait)
}
  }) 
ynames <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    ynames <- data() %>% unique(data()$Year)
  }
})

varcomp <- eventReactive(input$analysis, {
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    dummy1 <- data.frame()
    dummy2 <- data.frame()
    dummy3 <- data.frame()

    ynames <- unique(data()$Year)
    tnames <- unique(data()$Parameter)

    for(y in 1:length(ynames)){
      d2 <- data() %>% filter(Year == ynames[y]) %>%
        mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

      for (t in 1:length(tnames[t])) {
        d3 <- d2 %>% filter(Parameter == "tnames[t]") %>%
          mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

      m1 <- lm(Value ~ Zone + Product + Location, data = d3, na.action = "na.exclude")
      rclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter"= tnames[t])
      fclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter"= tnames[t])
      pred0 <- as_tibble(m1$fitted) %>% mutate("Year" = ynames[y], "Parameter" = tnames[t])
      dummy1 <- rbind(dummy1, rclic0)
      varcomp <- dummy1
     }
    }
  }
})

pred <- eventReactive(input$analysis, {
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    dummy1 <- data.frame()
    dummy2 <- data.frame()
    dummy3 <- data.frame()

   ynames <- unique(data()$Year)
   tnames <- unique(data()$Parameter)
   
   for(y in 1:length(ynames)){    # Running 
     d2 <- data() %>% filter(Year == ynames[y]) %>%
        mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
    for (t in 1:length(tnames)) {
      d3 <- d2 %>% filter(Parameter == tnames[t]) %>%
          mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
        
     m1 <- lm(Value ~ Zone + Product + Location, data = d3, na.action = "na.exclude")
     rclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter" = tnames[t])
     fclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter" = tnames[t])
        pred0 <- as_tibble(m1$fitted) %>% mutate("Year" = ynames[y], "Parameter" = tnames[t])
        dummy3 <- rbind(dummy3, pred0)
        pred <- dummy3
      }
    }
  }
})  

output$mytable <- renderDataTable(data())
output$ynames <- renderPrint({unique(data()$Year)})
output$tnames <- renderPrint({unique(data()$Parameter)})
output$varcomp <- renderDataTable(varcomp())
output$pred <- renderDataTable(pred())
})
```

##### Hard coded Code - this runs fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(readxl)
library(lme4)

shinyApp(
ui <- navbarPage("Pluto",
      tabPanel("Data Import & Preview",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(width = 2,
            fileInput("file1", "Upload the updated template (only 1 Sheet)", accept = ".xlsx")
            ),
          mainPanel(h2("Data Preview"), DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"), width = 4)
                        )) ,
        tabPanel("Data Analysis",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(width = 2, 
                 actionButton("analysis", "Fire")),
             
             fluidRow(width = 20,
               tabBox(id = "trans",
                 tabPanel("Names View", verbatimTextOutput("tnames", placeholder = T), 
                          verbatimTextOutput("ynames", placeholder = T)),
                 tabPanel("Variance Components", DT::dataTableOutput("varcomp")),
                 tabPanel("Pred Values", DT::dataTableOutput("pred"))
                 
                 )
              )
            )
          )
      ),
server <- function(input, output, session){
data <- reactive({
  req(input$file1)
  read_xlsx(input$file1$datapath)
  })

tnames <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
} else {
  tnames <- data() %>% unique(data()$Trait)
}
})
ynames <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    ynames <- data() %>% unique(data()$Year)
  }
})

varcomp <- eventReactive(input$analysis, {
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {

    dummy1 <- data.frame()
    dummy2 <- data.frame()
    dummy3 <- data.frame()

    ynames <- unique(data()$Year)
    tnames <- unique(data()$Parameter)

    #for(y in 1:length(ynames)){
      d2 <- data() %>% filter(Year == 2018) %>%
        mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

      #for (t in 1:length(tnames)) {
        d3 <- d2 %>% filter(Parameter == "LDPP") %>%
          mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

        m1 <- lm(Value ~ Zone + Product + Location, data = d3, na.action = "na.exclude")
        rclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
        fclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
        pred0 <- as_tibble(m1$fitted) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
        dummy1 <- rbind(dummy1, rclic0)
        varcomp <- dummy1
    # }
  #  }
  }
})

pred <- eventReactive(input$analysis, {
  if(is.null(input$file1)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    
    dummy1 <- data.frame()
    dummy2 <- data.frame()
    dummy3 <- data.frame()
    
    ynames <- unique(data()$Year)
    
    tnames <- unique(data()$Parameter)
    
   # for(y in 1:length(ynames)){
d2 <- data() %>% filter(Year == 2018) %>%
        mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
      
     # for (t in 1:length(tnames)) {
        d3 <- d2 %>% filter(Parameter == "LDPP") %>%
          mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
        
        m1 <- lm(Value ~ Zone + Product + Location, data = d3, na.action = "na.exclude")
        
       rclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
       fclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
       pred0 <- as_tibble(m1$fitted) %>% mutate("Year" = 2018, "Parameter" = "LDPP")
       dummy3 <- rbind(dummy3, pred0)
       pred <- dummy3
     # }
  #  }
  }
})  

output$mytable <- renderDataTable(data())
output$ynames <- renderPrint({unique(data()$Year)})
output$tnames <- renderPrint({unique(data()$Parameter)})
output$varcomp <- renderDataTable(varcomp())
output$pred <- renderDataTable(pred())
})
```

### Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it without using the `1:length` and just using the variable? For example: `for(y in ynames)` then `df %>% filter(Year == y)`.

Comment: Hello Alexb523, Thank you for your response. I did try your suggestion. I did not work for me. But below solution from YBS did work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter` has incorrect syntax.  Also, you have nesting `for` loops.  By switching outer `for` loop to `lapply`, and using `local` in the inner `for` loop, you can make it work.  Try this

```
  varcomp <- eventReactive(input$analysis, {
    req(data())
    if(is.null(input$file1)){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      dummy1 <- data.frame()
      dummy2 <- data.frame()
      dummy3 <- data.frame()
      
      ynames <- unique(data()$Year)
      tnames <- unique(data()$Parameter)
      n <- length(ynames)
      lapply(1:n, function(y) {
      #for(yy in 1:n){
        
          d2 <- data() %>% filter(Year == ynames[y]) %>%
            mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
          m <- length(tnames[y])
          for (t in 1:m) {
            local({
              t <- t
              d3 <- d2 %>% filter(Parameter == as.character(tnames[t])) %>%
                mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
              
              m1 <- lm(Value ~ Zone + Product + Location, data = d3, na.action = "na.exclude")
              rclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter"= tnames[t])
              fclic0 <- as_tibble(m1$coefficients) %>% mutate("Year"=ynames[y],"Parameter"= tnames[t])
              pred0 <- as_tibble(m1$fitted) %>% mutate("Year" = ynames[y], "Parameter" = tnames[t])
              dummy1 <<- rbind(dummy1, rclic0)
              #varcomp <<- dummy1
            })
            dummy2 <<- rbind(dummy2,dummy1)
          }
        #})
        
      #}
      })
      dummy2
    }
  })
```

You can try to implement the same in the `pred` eventReactive.

[image: output]

Comment: Hello YBS, That was very quick & helpful. It perfectly works the way I need. Much appreciated.  Couple of quick clarifying questions.

1. What does 'local({})' do?
2. Why doesn't the nested for loops work, after removing the syntax errors though?
3. Why do we need to create separate reactive events for each of the outputs. Here varcomp & pred & son on?

Comment: @SandeepPatil, Please accept the answer if this solution worked for you.  This might help others.  You can google on how to accept answers.  Your questions are good.  Perhaps you should do research on them, as I cannot answer briefly in the comments.  Generally `for` loops do no work well in Shiny (due to lazy evaluation); alternative is to use `lapply`.  Inside `for` loop also can be switched to `lapply`, then you don't need `local()`.